# Sticky nav bar, how to hide when scroll down and show when scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hide the sticky nav bar on scroll down and show it again whilst the screen is being scroll up. At the moment the sticky nav bar is still operating as normal without this affect.

Not sure what I need to do to fix it:

HTML:

```
<header id="site-header" class="header-footer-group _mPS2id-t mPS2id-target mPS2id-target-first mPS2id-target-last" role="banner">
    
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#site-header{
    opacity: 0.9;
    width:100% !important;
    z-index:99999;
  position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
    height:166px;
}

.navup{
    transform: translatey(-166px);
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var my_window = window;
var position = my_window.scrollTop;
    
my_window.scroll(function () {
    if (my_window.scrollTop  > position) {
        $('#site-header').addClass('navup');
    }else{
        $('#site-header').removeClass('navup');
    }
    
    position = my_window.scrollTop;
});
    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In first line of script, you should create a selector of window object, like: `$(window)`.
After that, add parenthesis after every `scrollTop` occurence, like this `scrollTop()` since it is a method, not a property.

This should do it:

```
var my_window = $(window);
var position = my_window.scrollTop();
    
my_window.scroll(function () {
    if (my_window.scrollTop()  > position) {
        $('#site-header').addClass('navup');
    }else{
        $('#site-header').removeClass('navup');
    }
    
    position = my_window.scrollTop();
});
```

Comment: Yeah this is strange because I did it like this to begin with but my console was throwing errors saying $ is not a function for $(window) and ScrollTop() is not a method